# How can I set stretch of verbatim to be different than "global" setting?

Tags: verbatim, line-spacing

In my file I need to use 1.5 line stretch. But, as for `verbatim` I need it to be 1.0. What should I add to preamble to achieve that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace} \setstretch{1.5}
\begin{document} 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Proin nibh augue, suscipit a, scelerisque sed, lacinia in, mi. Cras vel lorem. Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus. Phasellus pharetra nulla ac diam.
\begin{verbatim}
A = 5
B = 123
C = 123123
\end{verbatim}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Proin nibh augue, suscipit a, scelerisque sed, lacinia in, mi. Cras vel lorem. Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus. Phasellus pharetra nulla ac diam.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest another improvement:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace} \setstretch{1.5}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto{\verbatim}{\edef\tempstretch{\baselinestretch}\par\setstretch{1}}
\appto{\endverbatim}{\vspace{-\tempstretch\baselineskip}\vspace{\baselineskip}}
```

The first `\preto` does almost the same as David's trick, but it also saves the value of `\baselinestretch` that we use also at the end of the environment for making the spacing around the `verbatim` environment symmetric.

Answer (score 10):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace} \setstretch{1.5}
\let\oldv\verbatim
\def\verbatim{\par\setstretch{1}\oldv}
\begin{document} 
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Proin nibh augue, suscipit a, scelerisque sed, lacinia in, mi. Cras vel lorem. Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus. Phasellus pharetra nulla ac diam.
\begin{verbatim}
A = 5
B = 123
C = 123123
\end{verbatim}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Proin nibh augue, suscipit a, scelerisque sed, lacinia in, mi. Cras vel lorem. Etiam pellentesque aliquet tellus. Phasellus pharetra nulla ac diam.
\end{document}
```

Comment: stretch does not apply to first para?? And how come it does not need to be restored at end of the environment sine you adjust it before beginning the environment?

Comment: @PeterGrill The call `\begin{foo}` issues `\begingroup` before executing `\foo`. So `\setstretch{1} is executed *inside* the environment.

Comment: A `\par` should be added before `\setstretch{1}`.

Comment: David's solution doesn't work with my edited example. It changes stretching of the first paragraph.

Comment: Oh, it works with egreg's improval.

Comment: fix the definition as suggested by @egreg. I'll edit my answer. sorry.